# About EU fingerprints

Tags: visa-refusals

I need help for the Switzerland fingerprint
I have apply a treatment visa before 1 year and I got appeal without passport stamp , now I want apply visa from Sweden so is my fingerprint will show up or it's not in the Database  , please I need answer

Comment: You should assume that any details you have provided for an application for a Schengen visa will be available to any Schengen country you approach for a subsequent application. You should probably assume that is also true for the UK, the US, New Zealand, Australia and other western countries.

Comment: is that mean my fingerprint in the database after the rejected and will show up ,plus I didn't get EU visa before .

Comment: They probably can see your fingerprints while processing. And if you are worried that if they will find about your previous rejection, be sure that they will indeed. So no shenanigans in your current visa application.

Comment: On the plus side, you won't have to provide the biometrics *again*.

Comment: I find it very hard to understand your question. Does greatone's answer contain the information you needed? If so, please consider clicking the green checkmark next to it to show that it solved your problem. If not, it would probably help if you edited your question to explain the situation more. I'm not sure what you mean by "I got appeal without passport stamp."

Comment: hi.my story is that i have two nationality passport one is Yemen passport and other one is Somalian passport.before one year ago i request visa to Switzerland for my Yemen passport and they toke my fingerprint but they gave me rejected but not stamped on my passport now i wait sponsor from Sweden.my question is ?.Is there any possibility that my fingerprints will be shown up in the system ? and can I use my Somalian passport.

Answer (score 1):

Data in the VIS system which includes fingerprints is stored for five years. This is accessible to all Schengen countries. Non-Schengen countries have no access to VIS information.

https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system_en